# Why cant we get a file data from a RequestBody in java?

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to a server so i am trying to use @RequestBody to get the data of the file, but i am getting 415 error code while trying to upload a file.

So i have googled(got solution to upload a file) and got to know that i cant get file data from a request body. So i want to know why cant we access file data from request body as data will be sent in request body in HTTP requests, so i want to know how is the request happening in the case of uploading a file.

My server code before:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file)
{
}
```

Solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
{
}
```

Comment: Try this..                                                                                                           

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile uploadFile)
{
}

Comment: i know that it will work i want to know why cant we get it from @RequestBody

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically you could write your own [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) which would parse the full multipart request body, but you'd have to have a very specific target type that could handle all the parts.

You'll notice from the javadoc of [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html)

> Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body
>   of the web request.

that the intention is to bind the entirety of the request body to the method parameter. How do you bind every part of a multipart request to a single parameter? Something like a `MultiValueMap<String, Object>` ([which is what `FormHttpMessageConverter` uses when **writing** a multipart request](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html)). But that wouldn't be very useful because you'd have to check the type of each value.

It makes much more sense as a developer to specify exactly what you need. That's why `@RequestParam` and `@RequestPart` are available.

Answer (score 5):

Because the files are not the request body, they are part of it and there is no built-in HttpMessageConverter that can convert the request to an array of MultiPartFile.
Thats why it works `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files`

instead of

```
@RequestBody MultipartFile file
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can i fetch files and its contents using RequestBody parameters only? I am sending images as Multipart and along side that i am sending String Id for all images and i want to fetch it via Srping controller.